# How do I run Net::SSH and AMQP in the same EventMachine reactor?

Tags: ruby, amqp, eventmachine, gerrit, net-ssh

Some background: [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) [exposes an event stream through SSH](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.2/cmd-stream-events.html). It's a cute trick, but I need to convert those events into AMQP messages. I've tried to do this with [ruby-amqp](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp) and [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html) but, well, it doesn't seem as if the AMQP sub-component is even being run at all.

I'm fairly new to EventMachine. Can someone point out what I am doing incorrectly? The answer to "[Multiple servers in a single EventMachine reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158394/multiple-servers-in-a-single-eventmachine-reactor)) didn't seem applicable. The program, also available in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1249542) for easier access, is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                                                            

require 'rubygems'
require 'optparse'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'json'
require 'yaml'
require 'amqp'
require 'logger'

trap(:INT) { puts; exit }

options = {
  :logs => 'kili.log',
  :amqp => {
    :host => 'localhost',
    :port => '5672',
  },
  :ssh => {
    :host => 'localhost',
    :port => '22',
    :user => 'nobody',
    :keys => '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
  }
}
optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: kili [options]"
  opts.on( '--amqp_host HOST', 'The AMQP host kili will connect to.') do |a|
    options[:amqp][:host] = a
  end
  opts.on( '--amqp_port PORT', 'The port for the AMQP host.') do |ap|
    options[:amqp][:port] = ap
  end
  opts.on( '--ssh_host HOST', 'The SSH host kili will connect to.') do |s|
    options[:ssh][:host] = s
  end
  opts.on( '--ssh_port PORT', 'The SSH port kili will connect on.') do |sp|
    options[:ssh][:port] = sp
  end
  opts.on( '--ssh_keys KEYS', 'Comma delimeted SSH keys for user.') do |sk|
    options[:ssh][:keys] = sk
  end
  opts.on( '--ssh_user USER', 'SSH user for host.') do |su|
    options[:ssh][:user] = su
  end
  opts.on( '-l', '--log LOG', 'The log location of Kili') do |log|
    options[:logs] = log
  end
  opts.on( '-h', '--help', 'Display this screen' ) do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end


optparse.parse!
log = Logger.new(options[:logs])
log.level = Logger::INFO

amqp = options[:amqp]
sshd = options[:ssh]
queue= EM::Queue.new

EventMachine.run do

  AMQP.connect(:host => amqp[:host], :port => amqp[:port]) do |connection|
    log.info "Connected to AMQP at #{amqp[:host]}:#{amqp[:port]}"
    channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
    exchange = channel.topic("traut", :auto_delete => true)

    queue.pop do |msg|
      log.info("Pulled #{msg} out of queue.")
      exchange.publish(msg[:data], :routing_key => msg[:route]) do
        log.info("On route #{msg[:route]} published:\n#{msg[:data]}")
      end
    end
  end


  Net::SSH.start(sshd[:host], sshd[:user],
    :port => sshd[:port], :keys => sshd[:keys].split(',')) do |ssh|
    log.info "SSH connection to #{sshd[:host]}:#{sshd[:port]} as #{sshd[:user]} made."

    channel = ssh.open_channel do |ch|
      ch.exec "gerrit stream-events" do |ch, success|
        abort "could not stream gerrit events" unless success

        # "on_data" is called when the process writes something to                                                                                             
        # stdout                                                                                                                                               
        ch.on_data do |c, data|
          json = JSON.parse(data)
          if json['type'] == 'change-merged'
            project = json['change']['project']
            route = "com.carepilot.event.code.review.#{project}"
            msg = {:data => data, :route => route}
            queue.push(msg)
            log.info("Pushed #{msg} into queue.")
          else
            log.info("Ignoring event of type #{json['type']}")
          end
        end


    # "on_extended_data" is called when the process writes                                                                                                 
    # something to stderr                                                                                                                                  
    ch.on_extended_data do |c, type, data|
          log.error(data)
    end

    ch.on_close { log.info('Connection closed') }
      end
    end  
  end  

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Net::SSH is not asynchronous, so your `EventMachine.run()` is never reaching the end of the block, thus never resuming the reactor thread.  This causes the AMQP code to never start.  I would suggest running your SSH code within another thread.

Comment: Thank you. I ultimately decided to use [bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) as its use was conceptually more simple than running a few threads and communicating between them. See the final program [here](https://github.com/CarePilot/Traut/blob/master/samples/kili).

Comment: Probably a good idea.  Bunny keeps it simple if you don't need concurrency and maximum throughput.

Comment: Yep. I had a thread solution mostly working, but after thinking about it it seems I'd do better just to patch Gerrit to perform AMQP notifications natively.

Answer (score 3):

If you go back to EventMachine, give em-ssh https://github.com/simulacre/em-ssh a try.